# Want to know about automatic drop of data that no one references

Tags: memory-management, rust, garbage-collection, ownership

I don't think the garbace collection of rust is fully explained with only the scope of the ownership.

I have googled it, and this is what I've got.

1. [ temporary data ]

If you reference temporary data, lifetime of the data differs by the expression where it comes : at the end of the scope, or at the end of the expression.

Look for the further explanation in here :

https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/rust-1.36.0-docs-html/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes

2. [ reassignment of variables ]

```
let a = String::from("first");
a = String::from("second");
```

In above case, first string data automatically drops while second assignment.

However, I couldn't search for more information since then.

In my prediction,

Fields of structures and indexes of arrays may be considered as "an independent variable" so that changing them to be considered as an reassignment of variable.

```
struct A {
    a: String,
    b: String
}

let mut x = A {
    a: String::from("first"),
    b: String::from("second")
}

x.a = String::from("reassignment"); // first string drops here
```

Also, we all know that if a variable drops, it drops all of its contents. (as below)

```
{
let a = vec!(String::from("first"), String::from("second"));
} // all the strings are dropped here.
```

OK. Then what about more complicated stuffs??

`Box<T>` or `HashMap<String, i32>` ... etc... which is data that consumes ownership of anyother data.

What if we change its inner data??

Is it the same act as reassigning a field of structure??

I wonder if they're just complex structures or totally different objects.

Is there any other rules of "auto drop of data" I should know?

Comment: Ignoring `Rc` and `Arc`, then what garbage collection are you referring too? I'm not entirely sure how to interpret your question. Things are dropped e.g. when they go out of scope, or when you explicitly cause them to get dropped. Such as `drop(...)` or reassignments.

Comment: In Hashmap<String, i32>, deleting a <key, value> is also a explicit drop of a String? (which is a key value)

Comment: sorry for my bad english  :(

Comment: I've just got concious of "whether my code has any memory leaking or not".

Comment: If all of it boils down to "do I have any memory leaks?", then the answer is no. The code you've presented contains none. While yes `Box`, `Vec`, `HashMap` etc, use heap allocation, it is automatically freed when they are dropped. The only case where you'd need to worry about leaking memory, is if you use any [`leak()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=leak) related methods.

Comment: What about modification of inner value, not dropping the whole HashMap?

Comment: If you reassign to a variable or field, then the old values are dropped. If you `insert` twice, where the second `insert` overwrites the first. Then that similarly results in the first key-value pair getting dropped. In the specific example of `insert` then the old value is actually returned, i.e. `Option<V>`. But again, it automatically gets dropped if you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to known more and observe on automatic dropping then I recommend implementing Drop trait for a type. Rust doesn't have any garbage collector but the compiler does that job of adding instructions to cleanup the objects when they go out of scope.
Check this [Rust RAII](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/raii.html)

If you implement Drop trait and use logging or printing in drop fn then you known when it goes out of scope and reclaimed. In below example observe when the drop method of Data struct gets called when the object goes out of scope.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data{
    val: String
}

impl Drop for Data {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping for {:?}", self.val);
    }
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    {

        let mut dataref = Data{val: "d0".to_string()};
        
        {
            let data = Data{val: "d1".to_string()};
            let data2 = Data{val: "d2".to_string()};
            dataref = data2;
            
            println!("scope marker 1");
        }
        
        println!("scope marker 2");

        let mut map = HashMap::new();
        map.insert("k1".to_string(), Data{val:"v1".to_string()});
        println!("Before chaning for k1");
        map.insert("k1".to_string(), Data{val:"v1".to_string()});
        println!("Changed k1");

    }
    Ok(())
}
```